# Youtube Message: Channel Does Not Exist

Tags: youtube-api

Am using code provided by Google Developers to add Youtube button to website. When button is activated and the link to Youtube is made, I get a message on Youtube that "The channel does not exist."

See following code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC73r_CJEG-2kH6VY1lW7gIQ" data-
layout="default" data-count="hidden"></div>
```

Have also tried i frame api:

```
<iframe data-gapiattached="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" height="25px"
width="174px" style="padding-right: 10px"
src="http://www.youtube.com/subscribe_embed?bsv&amp;usegapi=1&amp;channel=UC73r_CJEG-
2kH6VY1lW7gIQ">
</iframe></h6>
<div align="center">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>`
```

With i frame api, web page shows Youtube icon with an exclamation point and the word "Error".

Am using Dreamweaver CS5 and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the code, you want generate a suscriber button.

you can see this doc:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button?hl=nl

This code Work for me.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channelid="UC73r_CJEG-2kH6VY1lW7gIQ" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/carlosrojas_o/9LLzjd7h/